# Using an ARC static library in a NON-ARC project

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, automatic-ref-counting, workspace

I am trying to get this sorted out. I know how to get an ARC project working with files or static lib's that are not using ARC. For instance, using the compiler flags **-fno-objc-arc**.

But what if I have a project that is not using ARC and want to include a static library compiled with ARC? Every time I want to build the project it is telling me that it doesn't recognize things like "strong, __unsafe_unretained,...".

Comment: Just curious, why can't you just turn on ARC for your project and add the compiler flag to all your files?  Is there a specific reason why you need to have ARC disabled?

Comment: The project was build a while ago and uses also a lot of other third party non-arc frameworks. So it would be a tedious process to go over all files and set the compiler flags. I was hoping for a better/cleaner solution. So I wouldn't need to fill out the compiler flags on more than 300 source files... :)

Comment: You do know that the ARC migrator allows you to basically "select all" files to add the flag to?  At least in Xcode 4.2, there's no need to do all the files manually.

Comment: After or before you must press the "precheck" button in the "Convert to Objective-C ARC..." menu item? Or is the ARC migrator located somewhere else?

Comment: It should be before, but I don't remember exactly because I don't have my Mac with me at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work fine - are you sure you're using the newest Apple compiler with this non-ARC project and not the GCC one?

Comment: Well if i would do that i need to remove all retain/release calls from my project and basically start to ARC the whole thing. And I don't want to do that because it has some old legacy code and a few structures in it.

Comment: No you're not - ARC is an extra compiler feature, you don't have to use it if you don't want to. Using newest Apple LLVM doesn't mean you have to use ARC - it's your choice (it even gives you that choice of using ARC or not when you're making new project). Using it doesn't mean you have to convert your old code to ARC.The difference is that it understands all those new keywords etc.

Comment: Jep you're right. I thought I had to start ARC'ing but he was just complaining on a few missed __bridged casts and a few other errors! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

To add on to shw's answer. Add -fobjc-arc to compiler flags under build phases to ARC files to make them compile correctly for non-ARC projects.

More info [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general)