# Using ARC library in non-ARC project

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, sbjson

ARC technology isn't being used in my project. I'm trying to add [SBJson](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/) library to it. I set -fobjc-arc flag for all files which have SBJson prefix, but during compilation process ARC semantic issue (Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership) appears in one class header, which is not related to SBJSon. Why doesn't it work?

Line with error:

```
    id *_controls;
```

I cannot show you my code because of commercial license of project, I appreciate your understanding.

Project compilation goes normally when I use older version of this library (without ARC).

Comment: can you just at-least give the line of the error

Comment: try id _controls; without the *

Comment: If you have set `-fobjc-arc` only for the SBJson files, why is your code `id *_controls;` compiled with ARC?

Comment: This is an actual reason I ask my question.

Comment: Try an explicit `-fno-objc-arc` on your project files (especially the one throwing the error).

Comment: There seems to be some .m file that includes this header and is compiled with ARC even if it shouldn't. If you go to the "Build ..." log in the "Log Navigator" you should be able to find out which .m file is causing the problem.

Comment: .pch includes this header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an ARC static library in a NON-ARC project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343916/using-an-arc-static-library-in-a-non-arc-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing an ARC violating construct into ARC'd files through inclusion.  You can't apply `-fno-objc-arc` to a single header file because that doesn't make sense.

Since it is in a header file, you will either need to use an #if pragma to switch between behaviors depending on whether an ARC or non-ARC .m file is being compiled.

A better solution, however, is to eliminate the issue entirely for both ARC and non-ARC.   Given that declaration, it pretty much has to be an instance variable (though it could be in a struct).

If it is an ivar, get rid of the declaration entirely.   Either expose it through `@property` or move it to the `.m` file if it does not need to be exposed in your public API.  Given the type, it really should be a private implementation detail with public API that makes accessing the contents a bit less pointer-magic.

---

In general, using C language arrays -- arrays of pointers -- to store Objective-C types is highly discouraged.   If `_controls` does need to be exposed as a publicly accessible thing (public to the other classes in your project), then refactor your code to use a collection class (i.e. typically an exposed `NSArray*` getter with an internal-only `NSMutableArray*` backing store -- like `subviews` on `UIView`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments, the precompiled header file includes a class header file that is not meant to be compiled with ARC. This is causing the error, because the precompiled header is also included by all SBJson files that are compiled with ARC.

I would suggest that you remove that class header file from the .pch file and include it only from the non-ARC source files, where needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't delete this file from .pch. But i decide to use static library of SBJSon.