# RestKit and AFNetworking configure non ARC Project

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking-2

I am developing an IOS application. My project non ARC project and targeting version is 5.0. I want to use RestKit last version. RestKit use AFNetworking library. But AFNetworking library supported min targeting version is 6.0 and also use ARC. How can I configure my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARC code (libraries) in non ARC Projects as well.. have a look on this [Using ARC library in non-ARC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588664/using-arc-library-in-non-arc-project) Also there are non ARC (earlier versions of lib) available on github as well..